# Critical points and manifolds

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology

This might be trivial but I was wandering if given any manifold $M$ and point $a\in M$ why is it that we can't just define a function that has $a$ as a non-degenerate critical point? I.e., what property of the manifold prevents certain points from being critical for any function?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "non-degenerate" critical point?

Comment: as in the hessian matrix is nonsingular

Comment: I suggest6, you ask your professor for a clarification since this claim is false as stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure of what exactly you're asking. If $M$ has dimension $n$ then I can take any function $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$ with a "nondegnerate" critical point at $0$ and which vanishes outside a ball, and then take a smooth chart on $M$ about my point $a\in M$ and identify it with $\mathbb R^n$. I then extend $f$ to be zero outside of this chart. In this way every point on $M$ can be made into the critical point of some function.

Comment: Right I thought of something similar as your explaination but when I asked my prof he said there is a relation between the gradient of the function and the manifold that prevents certain functions from being smooth on it. I might've misheard what he said but I do remember he gave some sort of reasoning. This is for Morse Theory, there is a theorem that states homotopy equivalence for certain subsets of the manifold

Comment: I don't know any morse theory, but I feel like more conditions would have to be placed on the type of functions you're looking at since one can always construct a smooth function with some property at a point and then extend it to zero everywhere else.

Comment: So does your professor want this to be a Morse function on $M$ with a critical point at $a$? Still I do not see a problem, because we can always take an isotopy switching any pair of points (assuming connectedness).